# Select/update printer driver in my default printer

Tags: powershell, command

i wonder how can i select this printer driver and set it to ny default printer?
Printer properties screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/az2OS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az2OS.png)

i've tried this line

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "EPSON LX Series 1 (80)" | set-printer "Microsoft Print to PDF"

and this line

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "EPSON LX Series 1 (80)" | Set-PrinterProperty "Microsoft Print to PDF"

but nothing happens when i checked in properties of my target printer
after command execution (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EfFO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EfFO.png)

i've tried this line

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "EPSON LX Series 1 (80)" | set-printer "Microsoft Print to PDF"

and this line

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "EPSON LX Series 1 (80)" | Set-PrinterProperty "Microsoft Print to PDF"

i was expecting changes from this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNmqK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNmqK.png) to this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/02maA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02maA.png)

Comment: Try `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Printer | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'EPSON LX Series 1 (80)'})[0] | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName SetDefaultPrinter`

Comment: thank you @Theo, now i can set a default printer to client pc's in organization. i added your code to my batch script. i've tested it and it worked very well.